# PHPstorm не видит библиотеку angularjs

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm

Не могу понять почему PHPStorm не определяет библиотеку angularJS хотя я её подключил верно
[image: angular in app]

[image: settings of app]

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, нет. Точнее, подключили Вы ее правильно, но это не та библиотека, которая нужна в данном случае. Для того, чтобы включить поддержку AngularJS для проекта, нужен файл angular.js (отладочная версия, не минифицированный и не скрэмблированный). Typescript stubs (d.ts) в данном случае не годятся. См. http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/, '`Include angular.js in Your Project`'